# Why is BeautifulSoup giving an empty data list while web scraping the desired information?

Tags: python, web-scraping

BeautifulSoup giving out an empty data list.

Hi, this is the URL I am trying to scrape: https://usautosummit.com/delegates/?/wp-login

The HTML for the page is:

```
<li class="x-block-grid-item">
<a href="https://usautosummit.com/register/delegate-registration-example/?job_title=&amp;company_name=" style="text-decoration: inherit; color: inherit;" data-wpel-link="internal">
<div class="g-summit-post g-summit-post-content">
<div class="x-feature-box g-summit-attendee man center-text top-text cf" style=" max-width: none;" data-x-element="feature_box" data-x-params="{&quot;child&quot;:false,&quot;graphicAnimation&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;graphicAnimationOffset&quot;:&quot;50&quot;,&quot;graphicAnimationDelay&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}">
<div class="x-feature-box-graphic square ">
<div class="x-feature-box-graphic-outer square" style="">
<div class="x-feature-box-graphic-inner square" style="font-size: 125px; width: 100%; max-width: 125px;">4
<img class="square" src="https://usautosummit.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/05/aptiv_logo_color_rgb.png" style="margin: 0 auto;">
</div></div></div><div class="x-feature-box-content ">
<h4 class="x-feature-box-title">
</h4>
<p class="x-feature-box-text">
<strong>SVP and Chief Technology Officer</strong>
<br>
<em>Aptiv</em>
<br>
</p></div></div></div></a></li>
```

I want to scrape the name of the company and the role for each year that is mentioned.

The code i have written for that is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://usautosummit.com/delegates/?/wp-login'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print (r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'x-feature-box-text'})
print(items)
```

Output I am getting is: []

I checked if the website is scrapable or not but the status code was 200 so that was not a problem.

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: There seems to be no tag `p` with the `x-feature-box-text` class. Are you sure you are parsing the right URL?

Comment: I am posting it again here https://usautosummit.com/delegates/?/wp-login

Comment: That is a protected content, we can't help you if you don't post the HTML

Comment: @Pinal, If I understand correctly, you have to insert a password, and that reveals the content behind the password box. You'd have to automate the insertion of the password and only after that reparse the HTML content for later use.

Comment: thank you @Cornul11 I am using Jupyter Notebook and it doesnt let me automate the password insertion. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @Pinal, take a look at the `selenium` library. You will have to also download a WebDriver, which will help you insert the password in the needed field and click the relevant button. After that, you would reparse the HTML and continue using BeautifulSoup to achieve what you need in this situation.